# IOS 9 Quick Action for icon

Tags: ios

I am trying to add Quick Action menu when using 3D Touch on my icon. My info.plist looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>0.3</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType</key>
            <string>UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeAdd</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Home</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>quickactions.sweefties.home</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile</key>
            <string>videow</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemSubtitle</key>
            <string>Launch video..</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Movies</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>quickactions.sweefties.movies</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType</key>
            <string>UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeShare</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Share</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>quickactions.sweefties.share</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType</key>
            <string>UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeCompose</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Message</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>quickactions.sweefties.message</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Somehow, when adding this code below, it gives me error when trying to run the project, or when trying to open the info.plist using "Property List".

```
<array>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType</key>
            <string>UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeAdd</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Home</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>quickactions.sweefties.home</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile</key>
            <string>videow</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemSubtitle</key>
            <string>Launch video..</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Movies</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>quickactions.sweefties.movies</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType</key>
            <string>UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeShare</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Share</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>quickactions.sweefties.share</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType</key>
            <string>UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeCompose</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Message</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>quickactions.sweefties.message</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Error message:

> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Any ideas what might be wrong here? I have tried using multiple different code but still error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your Deployment Target to 9.0 in the General section.

Then try to replace your code with this in the info.plist.

```
<key>UIApplicationShortcutItems</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType</key>
            <string>UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeAdd</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Home</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>quickactions.sweefties.home</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile</key>
            <string>videow</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemSubtitle</key>
            <string>Launch video..</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Movies</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>quickactions.sweefties.movies</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType</key>
            <string>UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeShare</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Share</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>quickactions.sweefties.share</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType</key>
            <string>UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeCompose</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Message</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>quickactions.sweefties.message</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!!